# Primitive function and integration by parts in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: integration

If $f(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $f^{'}(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, can we conclude that

1) $f(x)=\int^{x}_{a}f^{'}(x)\mathrm{d}x+f(a)$
2) integrate by parts as 
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f^{'}(x)e^{-ix\xi}\mathrm{d}x=\left[f(x)e^{-ix\xi}\right]\bigg|^{+\infty}_{-\infty}+i{\xi}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}\mathrm{d}x$$

since I can't find any evident theorem about it.

Comment: 1) is the [fundamental theorem of calculus!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part)

Comment: but that is in the case of $f(x)\in C([a,b])$

Comment: (for example) https://books.google.fr/books?id=xScFoMlGLe0C&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=integration+by+parts+lebesgue+integral&source=bl&ots=n5FuINdImb&sig=Q4LylWxZnQ07t1EBnQB58H0Dp1k&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNjq_CnqTJAhUGOhoKHVHKBwwQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=integration%20by%20parts%20lebesgue%20integral&f=false

Answer (score 0):

1/ yes !

2/ yes : if f is in $L^1(R)$, the integrated term is $0$ ( if not, $f$ is not integrable at $\pm\infty$).

This is in the theory of the Fourier transform.

Comment: but by what rule can we integrate that by parts?

Comment: (for example) https://books.google.fr/books?id=xScFoMlGLe0C&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=integration+by+parts+lebesgue+integral&source=bl&ots=n5FuINdImb&sig=Q4LylWxZnQ07t1EBnQB58H0Dp1k&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNjq_CnqTJAhUGOhoKHVHKBwwQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=integration%20by%20parts%20lebesgue%20integral&f=false